# What is the equivalent of for i in bin(n)[3:]: in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, fibonacci, modulo

I'm working through an algorithm for returning the modulo of a large fibonacci number. I found a fast, and efficient algorithm for determining the value using the following python:

```
def fib(n):
    v1, v2, v3 = 1, 1, 0    # initialise a matrix [[1,1],[1,0]]
    for rec in bin(n)[3:]:  # perform fast exponentiation of the matrix (quickly raise it to the nth power)
        calc = v2*v2
        v1, v2, v3 = v1*v1+calc, (v1+v3)*v2, calc+v3*v3
        if rec == '1':    
            v1, v2, v3 = v1+v2, v1, v2
    return v2
```

I'd love to understand how to achieve this in javascript, and the binary conversion line is hanging me up. 
Here the for loop uses a binary conversion of each integer, I'm presuming from 0 to n, and truncates the result to 3 places. There is also an equality check for 'rec' against a string representation of 1 inside the body of the loop. Can someone break this down? Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if its positive i think its just `my_number.tostring(2)` ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the JavaScript (ES6) equivalent:

```js
function fib(n) {
    let [v1, v2, v3] = [1, 1, 0]; // initialise a matrix [[1,1],[1,0]]
    for (i of (n).toString(2).slice(1)) {  // perform fast exponentiation of the matrix (quickly raise it to the nth power)
        let calc = v2*v2;
        [v1, v2, v3] = [v1*v1+calc, (v1+v3)*v2, calc+v3*v3];
        if (i === '1')
            [v1, v2, v3] = [v1+v2, v1, v2];
    }
    return v2;
}

// Demo
console.log(fib(15));
```

#### Differences between the Python and JavaScript version:

Where the Python `bin()` function produces a string with a "0b" prefix, the JavaScript `toString(2)` method will produce the string without that prefix. As the python code then strips the first 3 characters from it (with `[3:]`), the JavaScript equivalent should only strip one character (with `slice(1)` or `substr(1)`).

A Python multiple assignment translates in JavaScript to a destructuring assignment, which requires array literal notation.

The `in` used in the Python `for` loop translates to `of` in JavaScript (ES6). JavaScript also knows the `in` syntax, but that has a different meaning: *i* would then take the index values (which would start at 0 and then increment one by one) instead of the character content at that index.

In Python `==` performs a strict comparison. In Javascript one needs to use `===` for a strict comparison, although that in this case it would also work with `==` (non-strict comparison where 1 is considered equal with '1'), it is best practice to use `===` where possible.

#### About the algorithm

Note that the conversion to binary only happens once: only *n* is converted to a binary string. The algorithm does not need the first digit of that binary representation (which will always be a one, except when *n* is zero). So that digit (and the "0b" prefix) is stripped from it. So it is not that it truncates that string to 3 characters -- no, it strips the first three characters, i.e. "0b1" (or "0b0" when *n* is zero) is thrown out the window.

Then *i* takes the value of each of the characters of the remaining string of zeroes and ones. So in each iteration *i* is either '0' or '1'. The name choice *i* is not the best: traditionally *i* is used for integers, not characters, but in this code it is a character.